# How to delivered the URL of a Servlet to Java Class?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to delivered the URL of a servlet (MyServlet.java) to a java class (Test.java). Test.java is located in a Project.jar in folder lib of WEB-INF. So I have tried to pass the Servlet URL to Test.java

```java
    import projct.Test;

    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        public void init() throws ServletException {..}                

        @Override
        public void destroy() {..}

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

             new Test().setServleturl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);

        }
    }
```

The Test.java class looks like this:

```java
    public class Test {
        private static String var;

        public static String getVar() {
            return var;
        }

        public static void setVar(String var) {
            Test.var = var;
        }    
    }
```

After Diployment is the value of var still null.

What am I doing wrong?
And how can you write the URL from MyServlet.java in var from Test.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `setServleturl()` is in fact `setVar()`, because it wouldn't compile.

Of course it's null after deployment. `processRequest()` is only called when a request... is processed. Make an HTTP request to your servlet, and the code will be executed.

That said, what you have there seems like a really bad idea, and it's not thread-safe (`setVar()` and `getVar()` should be synchronized). Moreover, these methods should be called using `Test.setVar()`, and not `new Test().setVar()`, since they're static methods. What are you trying to achieve?

EDIT: it seems the problem is to read files from WEB-INF at deployment time. To do that, use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), and in its `contextInitialized()` method, get the servlet context from the event, and call `servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/theFileToLoad")`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your assumption is correct.I want to read the files from the folder, which is located in the same level as WEB-INF. But the java class is located in the project.jar in the lib folder of WEB-INF. Therefore, I can not use the FileInputStream() oder getClass().getResourceAsStream().